# Azure SQL database, hibernate -Table not found: hibernate_sequence

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, azure

I'm getting error `INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: hibernate_sequence`
which is odd as the table exist in my database and can be seen from visual studio. But still it complains? What could possible be the problem.

I use `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect` as 
my dialect.

Driver `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

When I set `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` to create, I get the some other errors regarding hibernate_sequence:

```
dec. 02, 2015 6:04:51 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
dec. 02, 2015 6:04:51 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.
dec. 02, 2015 6:04:51 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
dec. 02, 2015 6:04:51 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
dec. 02, 2015 6:04:51 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
dec. 02, 2015 6:04:51 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
dec. 02, 2015 6:04:51 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
dec. 02, 2015 6:04:51 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.
dec. 02, 2015 6:04:51 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
```

I don't really know where to go from here about this problem. I've been searching alot and unable to find any or properly understand the problem and solution.

Any help is appreciated alot.

Answer (score 0):

Its a first shot in the dark (doing a bit more research) Ensure you are using the schema name in front of your tablename

```
select * from youruser.hibernate_sequence
```

Comment: I'm not sure what user I should use, my azure user? (it contains invalid char ' ! '). If I just run select * from hibernate_sequence it returns "next_ val"

Comment: my Schema is dbo, doh. Well select * from dbo.hibernate_sequence returns "next_val" aswell.

Comment: Try adding dbo. to your table name to ensure there's no mapping on thst account